# Meta-answers - are they an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, not-an-answer

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395709/1594286) came up in the review queues, and I was going to mark it as not-an-answer but I couldn't decide whether to commit to that judgement.

It reads like a comment, starting with

> Welcome to SO. You might want to look at the SO help guide and how you can write a MVC question

At that point my finger was on the button. Later this person points out potentially duplicate questions and potentially relevant documentation. (I say potential because I haven't read it, and I'm not familiar enough on the topic to feel comfortable making that call).

Each individual part of this seems like a reason for closure;

- The quote above would have had it closed as a comment
- The references would have it be closed as a link-only answer.
- The link to the other stack overflow should possibly have been a duplicate flag.

I feel bad closing it because it's clear that the author put effort into it. But despite that, it still doesn't seem to meet the quality standards...

What are people's thoughts on this?

Comment: I mean... Efforts or not... This isn't up to our standards, and that should be it, no?

Comment: @Patrice although to a point I agree, it's members like this that have the potential to be decent contributors...

Comment: Well... Only if we explain to them the rules and how to abide by them, no? If we just let that behavior happen without explaining what to do while still following our standards, we're just getting a new contributor who will continue to post such answers

Comment: Sorry for reopening this and then closing it, I clicked reopen on accident trying to add some tags for you.

Answer (score 7):

Some things that come up at meta Stack Overflow deserve their own discussion. This topic though, has been so expertly covered by Shog9 at Meta Stack Exchange (originally posted to meta Stack Overflow in '13) that I will simply leave you with this:

> Folks aren't looking for "effort" because they think displays of struggle are some sort of magic pixie dust, able to turn a terrible, useless question into gold. They're looking for effort because the lack thereof is the most blatantly obvious hallmark of the thousands of terrible, terrible questions asked every day on Stack Overflow.

[And let you read the rest of the post and subsequent discussion over there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210868/178816).

Comment: Your quoted section sums up what I was thinking quite succinctly. You get very used to seeing the worst of the worst in the queues that stuff like this gleams like gold.